# React app looking for material-ui/core in Src folder and not node_modules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a material ui drawer menu (but due to the amount of links I need it to be nested).
I've found exactly what I need here,
https://medium.com/gammastack/making-a-nested-sidebar-menu-in-react-f8595031995e
(Same as the menu in material-ui site)

I have followed it to the letter (Many times now) and I'm getting this error

```
./src/MenuBar.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Collapse' in 'C:\Users\adejo\Desktop\MUI-problem\nested-menu\src'
```

It seems to me that it's looking in the Src folder for all of the mui components, and not node_modules (where I thought it would be).  I'm pretty new to all of this, and usually get by with Google, but I'm stuck on this one. Can anyone suggest how to go about resolving this?

I haven't included code as it is exactly as is on the link.
I have only changed what is on the link, I put the menuItems.json file in Src, and everything else is as it comes.

Code for MenuBar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import List from 'material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from 'material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from 'material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import Collapse from 'material-ui/core/Collapse'
import ExpandLess from 'material-ui/icons/ExpandLess'
import ExpandMore from 'material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'
import Drawer from 'material-ui/core/Drawer'
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/core/styles'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import menuItems from './menuItems'
const styles = {
  list: {
    width: 250,
  },
  links: {
    textDecoration:'none',
  },
  menuHeader: {
    paddingLeft: '30px'
  }
};
class MenuBar extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
    this.state = {}
  }
// this method sets the current state of a menu item i.e whether it is in expanded or collapsed or a collapsed state
handleClick( item ) {
    this.setState( prevState => ( 
      { [ item ]: !prevState[ item ] } 
    ) )
  }
// if the menu item doesn't have any child, this method simply returns a clickable menu item that redirects to any location and if there is no child this method uses recursion to go until the last level of children and then returns the item by the first condition.
handler( children ) {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const { state } = this
return children.map( ( subOption ) => {
      if ( !subOption.children ) {
        return (
          <div key={ subOption.name }>
            <ListItem 
              button 
              key={ subOption.name }>
              <Link 
                to={ subOption.url }
                className={ classes.links }>
                <ListItemText 
                  inset 
                  primary={ subOption.name } 
                />
              </Link>
            </ListItem>
          </div>
        )
      }
      return (
        <div key={ subOption.name }>
          <ListItem 
            button 
            onClick={ () => this.handleClick( subOption.name ) }>
            <ListItemText 
              inset 
              primary={ subOption.name } />
            { state[ subOption.name ] ? 
              <ExpandLess /> :
              <ExpandMore />
            }
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse 
            in={ state[ subOption.name ] } 
            timeout="auto" 
            unmountOnExit
          >
            { this.handler( subOption.children ) }
          </Collapse>
        </div>
      )
    } )
  }
render() {
    const { classes, drawerOpen, menuOptions } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={classes.list}>
        <Drawer 
          variant="persistent" 
          anchor="left"
          open
          classes={ { paper: classes.list } }>
          <div>
            <List>
              <ListItem 
                key="menuHeading"
                divider
                disableGutters
              >
                <ListItemText
                className={ classes.menuHeader }
                  inset
                  primary="Nested Menu"
                />
              </ListItem>
            { this.handler( menuItems.data ) }
            </List>
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MenuBar)
```

Thank You

Comment: May i see your imports in the MenuBar.jsx file?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I have edited the main to include the code for the MenuBar.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your node_modules folder for material-ui folder. check if its `@material-ui` or just `material-ui`.

your imports are wrong. it should be as follows with @ sign.

e.g.

```
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
```

if you have freshly install material-ui then it may be `@mui` folder with imports as follows

```
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
```

Comment: Yeah, thats done it, I did try that but I must have missed something, but, yeah its all good now.  Thanks Man